# On the anti-equivalence of affine schemes with commutative rings

Tags: algebraic-geometry, category-theory

There is an equivalence $\mathbf{Aff}\simeq \mathbf{CRing}^{\text{op}}$ between the category of affine schemes and the category opposite to the category of all commutative rings.

If we instead consider the category $\mathbf{CRing}_{\star}^{\text{op}}$ of commutative rings with a unit, does the equivalence above restrict to an equivalence of $\mathbf{CRing}_{\star}^{\text{op}}$ with some (describable) subcategory of $\mathbf{Aff}$? (Well it must do, so I guess my question is, what exactly is that subcategory?)

Answer (score 5):

You probably misunderstood : there is an anti-equivalence between affine schemes and *unital* commutative rings. The existence of a unit is already assumed in the initial construction.